# SQL Server trigger to check if column value was changed to insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, triggers

I have around 25 tables that each have 3 triggers (insert, update, delete) to generate logs on user actions. All these tables get updated each time there is an edit in the UI, though their value is not changed in the UI.

In such case I can't just check for if a column is updated, I need to check if previous updated value is not the same as the newly updated value so then I can insert to my log table. Also, I need to insert all updated table values to log table as a string separated by comma.

Is there any efficient way how to handle this?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Activity_Update]
ON [dbo].[Activity]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 
    SET @result = ' '

    DECLARE @id INT;
    SELECT @id = i.ID FROM inserted i;      

    IF UPDATE(deptNotes) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @OldValue NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SELECT TOP 1 @OldValue = deptNotes 
        FROM Activity 
        WHERE id = @id 
        ORDER BY Timestamp DESC

        IF (@OldValue != (SELECT i.deptNotes FROM inserted i))        
        BEGIN
            IF ((SELECT i.deptNotes FROM inserted i) != ' ')
               SELECT @result =  @result + ',' + 'Modified dept. Notes'
            ELSE
               SELECT @result =  @result + ',' + 'Removed dept. Notes'
        END
   END

   IF UPDATE(deptActivityID) 
   BEGIN
       DECLARE @OldValue1 NVARCHAR(MAX)

       SELECT TOP 1 @OldValue1 = deptActivityID 
       FROM Activity 
       WHERE id = @id  
       ORDER BY Timestamp DESC

       IF (@OldValue1 != (SELECT i.deptActivityID FROM inserted i))           
       BEGIN
           SELECT @result =  @result + ',' + 'Changed dept. Activity  ' 
       END
    END

    IF UPDATE(SubmissionDate) 
    BEGIN
    declare @OldValue2 nvarchar(max)
    select Top 1 @OldValue2 = submissiondate from [Activity] where id=@id Order by Timestamp DESC

     If (@OldValue2 != (select i.submissiondate from inserted i))         
     BEGIN
     Select @result =  @result + ',' + 'Changed application date - ' + '"' + (select cast(i.submissiondate as nvarchar(500)) from inserted i)+ '"' 
     END
     END


     INSERT [Activity]
     ( 
       [deptActivityID], 
       [deptNotes], 
       [SubmissionDate], 
       [Username], 
       [Operation], 
       [Comment]
       )
       SELECT 
       v.deptActivityID, 
       v.deptNotes, 
       v.SubmissionDate,
       v.[LastEditBy],
       'update', 
       @result
       FROM inserted v
       END
       GO
```

Comment: What edition of SQL?

Comment: Sql Server 2012.

Comment: I meant like Developer or Enterprise. If one of those two, you could use Change Data Capture and probably save yourself a lot of headache

Comment: Sql Server 2012 Enterprise

Comment: Then Change Data Capture might be something to look into. Basically it asynchronosuly logs all changes you make to a table (I know you said you only wanted various changes, but unless disk space is a your limiting factor, you might just take the philosophy "more is better"). You can also find out which values change using a number of in built CDC functions.

Comment: Okay, Will  try Data capture. Thanks.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @id = i.ID FROM inserted i; ` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: _"...though their value is not changed in the UI."_  Fix that, because that is crappy, lazy, inefficient application coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `deleted` table to find out what was the old value and `inserted` for the new value. Also note that INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE may affect more than one rows, so you trigger should handled that.

below trigger code will gives you list of rows for any change in deptNotes.

```
select  'deptActivityID ' + d.deptActivityID +
        ' Changed from ' + d.deptNotes + ' to ' + i.deptNotes
from    deleted d
        inner join inserted i   on  d.deptActivityID    = i.deptActivityID
where   d.deptNotes <> i.deptNotes
```

If your deptNotes may contains NULL value, you need to use ISNULL() to handle that